# How can I get the data inside a javascript tag for a web graph, so I can make my own graph?

Tags: javascript, python, regex, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

So far using the python libraries *twill* and *beautifulsoup* I was able to log into my utility company's website, and get to the page with my usage data for gas and electricity respectively.  They actually made a nice plot with javascript, and the raw data is available buried in there.

The *twill* library very nicely displays the composition of web forms #1, #2, #3, etc using `showforms()`, `show()`, etc, but not javascript elements so far as I can tell.  *beautifulsoup* seems to be able to display html elements, like the title of the webpage eg:`title1 = soup1.html.head.title`, but I can't seem to get it to list the javascript elements (there are like 4 or 5 different javascripts on the page, one of which contains the data below).

Is there any way to use something like `showjavascript()` or `soup1.html.body.javascript` in *twill* or *beautifulsoup* respectively, to access this javascript data and perhaps parse it for import into *matplotlib* or other python plotting package?

the data in the javascript element looks like this (you can see me, the neighbors, and the efficient neighbors):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
window.seriesDTO = {
  "series" : [ {
    "id" : "YOU",
    "data" : [ {
      "startDate" : "Fri, 30 Aug 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Mon, 23 Sep 2013 23:59:59",
      "value" : 66,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Sun, 01 Sep 2013 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 30 Aug 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Mon, 23 Sep 2013 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Tue, 24 Sep 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Tue, 22 Oct 2013 23:59:59",
      "value" : 85,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Tue, 01 Oct 2013 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Tue, 24 Sep 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Tue, 22 Oct 2013 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Wed, 23 Oct 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Thu, 21 Nov 2013 23:59:59",
      "value" : 135,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Fri, 01 Nov 2013 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Wed, 23 Oct 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Thu, 21 Nov 2013 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Fri, 22 Nov 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Mon, 23 Dec 2013 23:59:59",
      "value" : 134,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Sun, 01 Dec 2013 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 22 Nov 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Mon, 23 Dec 2013 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Tue, 24 Dec 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Thu, 23 Jan 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 72,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Wed, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Tue, 24 Dec 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Thu, 23 Jan 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Fri, 24 Jan 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Mon, 24 Feb 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 109,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Sat, 01 Feb 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 24 Jan 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Mon, 24 Feb 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Tue, 25 Feb 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Tue, 25 Mar 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 84,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Sat, 01 Mar 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Tue, 25 Feb 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Tue, 25 Mar 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Wed, 26 Mar 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Thu, 24 Apr 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 86,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Tue, 01 Apr 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Wed, 26 Mar 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Thu, 24 Apr 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Fri, 25 Apr 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Fri, 23 May 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 56,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Thu, 01 May 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 25 Apr 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Fri, 23 May 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Sat, 24 May 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Tue, 24 Jun 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 76,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Sun, 01 Jun 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Sat, 24 May 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Tue, 24 Jun 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Wed, 25 Jun 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Thu, 24 Jul 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 72,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Tue, 01 Jul 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Wed, 25 Jun 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Thu, 24 Jul 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Fri, 25 Jul 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Mon, 25 Aug 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 81,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Fri, 01 Aug 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 25 Jul 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Mon, 25 Aug 2014 23:59:59"
    } ],
    "unit" : "KWH",
    "precision" : 0
  }, {
    "id" : "NEIGHBORS",
    "data" : [ {
      "startDate" : "Fri, 30 Aug 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Mon, 23 Sep 2013 23:59:59",
      "value" : 257.958526611328125,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Sun, 01 Sep 2013 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 30 Aug 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Mon, 23 Sep 2013 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Tue, 24 Sep 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Tue, 22 Oct 2013 23:59:59",
      "value" : 316.710968017578125,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Tue, 01 Oct 2013 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Tue, 24 Sep 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Tue, 22 Oct 2013 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Wed, 23 Oct 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Thu, 21 Nov 2013 23:59:59",
      "value" : 373.00909423828125,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Fri, 01 Nov 2013 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Wed, 23 Oct 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Thu, 21 Nov 2013 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Fri, 22 Nov 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Mon, 23 Dec 2013 23:59:59",
      "value" : 442.25927734375,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Sun, 01 Dec 2013 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 22 Nov 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Mon, 23 Dec 2013 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Tue, 24 Dec 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Thu, 23 Jan 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 389.46453857421875,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Wed, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Tue, 24 Dec 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Thu, 23 Jan 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Fri, 24 Jan 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Mon, 24 Feb 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 402.319488525390625,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Sat, 01 Feb 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 24 Jan 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Mon, 24 Feb 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Tue, 25 Feb 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Tue, 25 Mar 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 319.855438232421875,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Sat, 01 Mar 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Tue, 25 Feb 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Tue, 25 Mar 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Wed, 26 Mar 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Thu, 24 Apr 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 328.7225341796875,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Tue, 01 Apr 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Wed, 26 Mar 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Thu, 24 Apr 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Fri, 25 Apr 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Fri, 23 May 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 301.809600830078125,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Thu, 01 May 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 25 Apr 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Fri, 23 May 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Sat, 24 May 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Tue, 24 Jun 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 324.0477294921875,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Sun, 01 Jun 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Sat, 24 May 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Tue, 24 Jun 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Wed, 25 Jun 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Thu, 24 Jul 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 291.14556884765625,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Tue, 01 Jul 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Wed, 25 Jun 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Thu, 24 Jul 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Fri, 25 Jul 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Mon, 25 Aug 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 326.228668212890625,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Fri, 01 Aug 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 25 Jul 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Mon, 25 Aug 2014 23:59:59"
    } ],
    "unit" : "KWH",
    "precision" : 0
  }, {
    "id" : "EFFICIENT_NEIGHBORS",
    "data" : [ {
      "startDate" : "Fri, 30 Aug 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Mon, 23 Sep 2013 23:59:59",
      "value" : 87.5,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Sun, 01 Sep 2013 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 30 Aug 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Mon, 23 Sep 2013 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Tue, 24 Sep 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Tue, 22 Oct 2013 23:59:59",
      "value" : 112.07543182373046875,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Tue, 01 Oct 2013 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Tue, 24 Sep 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Tue, 22 Oct 2013 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Wed, 23 Oct 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Thu, 21 Nov 2013 23:59:59",
      "value" : 123,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Fri, 01 Nov 2013 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Wed, 23 Oct 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Thu, 21 Nov 2013 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Fri, 22 Nov 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Mon, 23 Dec 2013 23:59:59",
      "value" : 143,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Sun, 01 Dec 2013 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 22 Nov 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Mon, 23 Dec 2013 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Tue, 24 Dec 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Thu, 23 Jan 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 116,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Wed, 01 Jan 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Tue, 24 Dec 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Thu, 23 Jan 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Fri, 24 Jan 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Mon, 24 Feb 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 131,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Sat, 01 Feb 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 24 Jan 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Mon, 24 Feb 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Tue, 25 Feb 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Tue, 25 Mar 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 109,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Sat, 01 Mar 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Tue, 25 Feb 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Tue, 25 Mar 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Wed, 26 Mar 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Thu, 24 Apr 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 105,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Tue, 01 Apr 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Wed, 26 Mar 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Thu, 24 Apr 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Fri, 25 Apr 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Fri, 23 May 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 103,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Thu, 01 May 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 25 Apr 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Fri, 23 May 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Sat, 24 May 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Tue, 24 Jun 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 119,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Sun, 01 Jun 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Sat, 24 May 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Tue, 24 Jun 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Wed, 25 Jun 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Thu, 24 Jul 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 102,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Tue, 01 Jul 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Wed, 25 Jun 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Thu, 24 Jul 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "startDate" : "Fri, 25 Jul 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Mon, 25 Aug 2014 23:59:59",
      "value" : 104,
      "estimated" : false,
      "shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling" : true,
      "startOfMajorityMonth" : "Fri, 01 Aug 2014 00:00:00",
      "firstMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lastMajorityMonth" : null,
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 25 Jul 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Mon, 25 Aug 2014 23:59:59"
    } ],
    "unit" : "KWH",
    "precision" : 0
  }, {
    "id" : "BILL_IDENTIFIERS",
    "data" : [ {
      "value" : 1,
      "year" : 2013,
      "startDate" : "Fri, 30 Aug 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Mon, 23 Sep 2013 23:59:59",
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 30 Aug 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Mon, 23 Sep 2013 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "value" : 2,
      "year" : 2013,
      "startDate" : "Tue, 24 Sep 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Tue, 22 Oct 2013 23:59:59",
      "lowerDate" : "Tue, 24 Sep 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Tue, 22 Oct 2013 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "value" : 3,
      "year" : 2013,
      "startDate" : "Wed, 23 Oct 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Thu, 21 Nov 2013 23:59:59",
      "lowerDate" : "Wed, 23 Oct 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Thu, 21 Nov 2013 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "value" : 4,
      "year" : 2013,
      "startDate" : "Fri, 22 Nov 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Mon, 23 Dec 2013 23:59:59",
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 22 Nov 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Mon, 23 Dec 2013 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "value" : 1,
      "year" : 2014,
      "startDate" : "Tue, 24 Dec 2013 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Thu, 23 Jan 2014 23:59:59",
      "lowerDate" : "Tue, 24 Dec 2013 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Thu, 23 Jan 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "value" : 2,
      "year" : 2014,
      "startDate" : "Fri, 24 Jan 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Mon, 24 Feb 2014 23:59:59",
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 24 Jan 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Mon, 24 Feb 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "value" : 3,
      "year" : 2014,
      "startDate" : "Tue, 25 Feb 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Tue, 25 Mar 2014 23:59:59",
      "lowerDate" : "Tue, 25 Feb 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Tue, 25 Mar 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "value" : 4,
      "year" : 2014,
      "startDate" : "Wed, 26 Mar 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Thu, 24 Apr 2014 23:59:59",
      "lowerDate" : "Wed, 26 Mar 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Thu, 24 Apr 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "value" : 5,
      "year" : 2014,
      "startDate" : "Fri, 25 Apr 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Fri, 23 May 2014 23:59:59",
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 25 Apr 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Fri, 23 May 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "value" : 6,
      "year" : 2014,
      "startDate" : "Sat, 24 May 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Tue, 24 Jun 2014 23:59:59",
      "lowerDate" : "Sat, 24 May 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Tue, 24 Jun 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "value" : 7,
      "year" : 2014,
      "startDate" : "Wed, 25 Jun 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Thu, 24 Jul 2014 23:59:59",
      "lowerDate" : "Wed, 25 Jun 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Thu, 24 Jul 2014 23:59:59"
    }, {
      "value" : 8,
      "year" : 2014,
      "startDate" : "Fri, 25 Jul 2014 00:00:00",
      "endDate" : "Mon, 25 Aug 2014 23:59:59",
      "lowerDate" : "Fri, 25 Jul 2014 00:00:00",
      "upperDate" : "Mon, 25 Aug 2014 23:59:59"
    } ]
  } ],
  "sufficientData" : true
};
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the javascript code with [`slimit`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/slimit) package:

> SlimIt is a JavaScript minifier written in Python. It compiles
>   JavaScript into more compact code so that it downloads and runs
>   faster.
>
> SlimIt also provides a library that includes a JavaScript parser,
>   lexer, pretty printer and a tree visitor.

In your case, you can apply it by finding the first assignment to an object:

```
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from slimit import ast
from slimit.parser import Parser
from slimit.visitors import nodevisitor


data = """
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
window.seriesDTO = {
...
};
})();
</script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

parser = Parser()
tree = parser.parse(soup.script.text)

json_data = next(node.right.to_ecma() for node in nodevisitor.visit(tree)
                 if isinstance(node, ast.Assign) and isinstance(node.right, ast.Object))

print json.loads(json_data)
```

Prints a Python dictionary:

```
{u'series': [{u'data': [{u'endDate': u'Mon, 23 Sep 2013 23:59:59',
                         u'estimated': False,
                         u'firstMajorityMonth': None,
                         u'lastMajorityMonth': None,
                         u'lowerDate': u'Fri, 30 Aug 2013 00:00:00',
                         u'shouldUseMajorityMonthForBilling': True,
                         u'startDate': u'Fri, 30 Aug 2013 00:00:00',
                         u'startOfMajorityMonth': u'Sun, 01 Sep 2013 00:00:00',
                         u'upperDate': u'Mon, 23 Sep 2013 23:59:59',
                         u'value': 66},
...
{u'endDate': u'Mon, 25 Aug 2014 23:59:59',
                         u'lowerDate': u'Fri, 25 Jul 2014 00:00:00',
                         u'startDate': u'Fri, 25 Jul 2014 00:00:00',
                         u'upperDate': u'Mon, 25 Aug 2014 23:59:59',
                         u'value': 8,
                         u'year': 2014}],
              u'id': u'BILL_IDENTIFIERS'}],
 u'sufficientData': True}
```